# How to set screen refresh rate on Windows 10 DirectX

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display, directx, refresh-rate

I use a Lenovo Legion laptop for gaming (Windows 10 home), connected to an external screen with hdmi, Windows is set to duplicate the same image on both screens, the graphic card is the Nvidia 1050TI.

When I do not use games the external monitor works at Full Hd resolution at 60 Hz, matching the configuration in the Windows display settings.

When instead I use **some** games the monitor displays a warning that says "For best results use 1980x1080 @ 60 Hz". Other games run at 60Hz so the monitor does not display a warning.

If I check on monitor information when I see the warning it says that it is running at 75Hz instead of 60.

I checked in the video options of the games with wrong refresh, they do not have options to change it.

What can I do in order to have all games running correctly at 60Hz on the external screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do as follow:
1- Right click on you desktop choose display settings
2- scroll down and choose advanced display settings
3 - select the monitor and click on gpu proprieties for that screen 
4 - in the second tab you can select the refresh rate.

hope it helps.